# Structural equations models (SEM) with time series data

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I'm quite new to SEM and I'd like to use them to model a system in which there could be either a direct and an indirect effect between some variables. The indirect effect would, in my case, be mediated through a latent variable (similar to the MIMIC model, for my little understanding).

The doubt that I have is that my data comes from a multivariate time series which shows some autocorrelation and I am afraid that this is something that needs to be considered during the analysis.
Does anyone know if I need to do something in particular to account for the autocorrelation?

I mostly work in R so ideally I'd need something which is implementable in `lavaan`, but general considerations are, of course, more than welcome.

Comment: Dynamic Structural Equation Models might be what you are looking for. The input matrix would not be a simple covariance matrix, but a covariance matrix with lagged blocks; it's a block Toeplitz matrix.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how to implement such approach? Thanks!